# Assign Dropdownlist selected value from code behind throws Error

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

When I tried to assign a selected value to dropdownlist from session in the code behind, I get this error.

> An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code. 
>   Additional information: Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList.

The error throws in the Jquery functions after compiling the code behind screen. 
Even I used `dropdown.ClearSelection()`, but the issue not resolved.

Please Help...

Thanks and regards...!

Comment: Can you show what is happening in code behind?

Comment: @VDWWD, dropdown.ClearSelection();                                                                                   dropdown.selectedValue = "UserName"; this is how i set the selected value in code behind. And it throws error in front end.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear you must use
dropdown.SelectedValue="UserName";
when there is data in dropdown and even have that value which you want to set.
But in case you don't have data in dropdown try
dropdown.text="UserName";

Comment: Thanks for your Answer...!  My issue is when i set the selected value from code behind, I have values in the datasource of the dropdownlist and its selected value gets selected the first item in the list by default. But I want to set another value as selectedItem of the dropdownlist.

Comment: Actually just do a check for me the value you  are trying to set in dropdown ,does the value occur twice or more times in datasource. Your error message said could not select multiple items in dropdownlist...This error only means that the value you are setting is more than once and dropdown isgetting confused with which one to set.Just try to set any other value and see if it works.